# Docker-compose for task-based Flask API with Redis and rq

Tags: python, flask, redis, dockerfile, docker

I am not a Docker guru or expert in Flask or Redis. However, I need to leverage these technologies. I managed to cobble something together that works and would like to submit it for review.

The MWE repository [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-nuxt-flask-redis-rq) has three main directories:

1. backend: the task-based Flask API
2. frontend: a Nuxt app
3. pyapp: a custom python module used by backend

In addition to the docker file, I fear the flask app and worker are not properly set up.

### Flask

#### backend/manage.py

```
import redis
from flask_script import Server, Manager
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
from uwsgi import app

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command(
    'runserver',
    # Server(port=5000, use_debugger=True, use_reloader=True))
    Server(port=9061, use_debugger=True, use_reloader=True))
    # flask is on 9061 via docker

@manager.command
def runworker():
    redis_url = app.config['REDIS_URL']
    redis_connection = redis.from_url(redis_url)
    with Connection(redis_connection):
        #worker = Worker(app.config['QUEUES'])
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

#### backend/uwsgi.py

```
import os, sys
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

from app.factory import create_app

app = create_app()

# application = DispatcherMiddleware(app)
```

#### backend/deploy.sh

```
exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:9061 --reload uwsgi:app
```

#### backend/app/factory.py

```
'''-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
IMPORTS
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'''
import os
# for main flask app
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

# blueprints of the app
from .api.views import (bp as bp_api)
from . import settings
from pyapp import __name__, __version__

def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(bp_api, url_prefix='/api')
    app.config.from_object(settings)
    CORS(app)
    return app
```

#### backend/app/settings.py

```
import os, sys

APP_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'not_secret')


LISTEN = ['high', 'default', 'low']
REDIS_URL = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT = 10
```

---

### Docker

#### docker-compose

My docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt: # frontend
    image: frontend
    container_name: nuxt
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "npm run dev"
    environment:
      - HOST
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/assets:/src/assets
      - ./frontend/components:/src/components
      - ./frontend/layouts:/src/layouts
      - ./frontend/pages:/src/pages
      - ./frontend/plugins:/src/plugins
      - ./frontend/static:/src/static
      - ./frontend/store:/src/store

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    container_name: ngx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nuxt

  flask: # backend
    image: backend
    container_name: flask
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
    command: bash deploy.sh
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL
      - PYTHONPATH
    volumes:
      - ./backend/app:/app/app/
      - ./backend/manage.py:/app/manage.py
    ports:
      - '9061:9061'
    expose:
      - '9061'
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    image: backend
    container_name: worker
    command: python3 manage.py runworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL
      - PYTHONPATH

  redis: # for workers
    image: redis:5.0.3-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    expose:
      - '6379'
```

#### Flask service

The Flask docker file looks like:

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-pip

# Layer requriments and install before copying files as
# requirments are less likely to change
ADD ./backend/requirements.pip /app/
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.pip


# add custom python module
ADD ./pyapp /pyapp
RUN pip3 install -e /pyapp

# Change into app
WORKDIR /app


# Add contents of "flask_app" sub-project dir to /app/
ADD ./backend /app/
```

#### Nuxt service

The Nuxt dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:10.15

ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

# changed context from inside nuxt_app to this repo's root
# ADD . ${APP_ROOT}
ADD ./frontend ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
```

Comment: Your repository diverged a little since this post was done. I'll review this based on what's posted here noting that splitting the `docker-compose` for different environments like you've done is part of the review.